# Static bool variable in c++ Method

Tags: c++, methods, static, boolean

I have a simple code that behaves differently from what I expected. I would really love some insights and thoughts.

I have a simple code in member function that looks like that :

```
SOME~MEMBER~FUNCTION~IMPLEMENTATION
{
static bool a = false;

m_b = a; //m_b is a Boolean member of the parent class
}
```

before the assignment (m_b = a) on watch window I see m_b with 1 value and a with 0 value.

after the assignment (m_b = a) I would expect b to have a false value.
but when I check its value with a debugger watch window it shows 2 value and not 0, which always yields true.

anyone has any idea what am I missing? it looks simple but I dont really get what went wrong

more information : 
when i do if(a) it treats a like a true value, although it shows its a 0 on watch window, and its initiated with false.
really confusing

Comment: If you don't use these variables the compiler may generate any code for the optimization purpose. The assembly code may even fail to align with the C++ code, so the debugger doesn't show you what you expect.

Comment: I forgot to mention that b is being used and its a member variable, i just wanted to simplify my question. i will edit it

Comment: In the description of the problem you are mixing bool/int: sometimes you say that it has values 0/1/2, sometimes you say true/false. Please explain what you are actually inspect in the watch window.

Answer (score 1):

***Notice**: This answer was written before an important edit of the question was made. I won't update it unless OP provides us with sufficient information, ideally an MCVE.*

---

Unless you make the value of `b` part of the observable behaviour of your program, the compiler is free to optimize it as it see fit. This is this optimization that you observe through your debugger.

Try printing the value of `b` or `assert(!b)`, etc.

Comment: I edited the post. I'm sorry for misunderstanding wanted to simplify my question but it gave false details

Comment: @itai that's why you should always provide a [mcve].

Comment: I also expect that the fact that m_b is a data member of the *parent* class is important.